# XSLT not outputting tags only text

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

I have looked at this question which is the same issue as I am having:
[XSL Conversion XML->XML outputs only text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845104/xsl-conversion-xml-xml-outputs-only-text)

However I declared a default namespace and the tags are still not being created, I'm just getting a block of text.

Here is the start of my XSLT (it's huge so I won't post the lot)

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">

    <xsl:template match="/x">
        <PatientData>
            <xsl:value-of select="x:Patientdata"/>
            <Versionnumber>
                <xsl:value-of select="x:Patientdata/Versionnumber"/>
            </Versionnumber>
            <Patient>
                <xsl:value-of select="x:Patientdata/Patient"/>
                <PatientCharacterstics>
                    <xsl:value-of select="x:Patientdata/Patient/PatientCharacteristics"/>
                    <patientCode>
                        <xsl:value-of select="x:Patientdata/Patient/PatientCharacteristics/patientCode"/>
                    </patientCode>
                    <identifier>
                        <xsl:value-of select="x:Patientdata/Patient/PatientCharacteristics/identifier"/>
                    </identifier>
                    <sex>
                        <xsl:value-of select="x:Patientdata/Patient/PatientCharacteristics/sex"/>
                    </sex>
                    <dateOfBirth>
                        <xsl:value-of select="x:Patientdata/Patient/PatientCharacteristics/dateOfBirth"/>
                    </dateOfBirth>
                    <DebutOfSymptoms>
                        <xsl:value-of select="x:Patientdata/Patient/PatientCharacteristics/DebutOfSymptoms"/>
                    </DebutOfSymptoms>
```

And all I am getting is a giant block of text as output, not one single tag.

Edit: As requested some sample input XML, its a condensed version to illustrate, basically the xslt is just rearranging the order of elements of an xml file:

```
<Patientdata>
<Versionnumber>1</Versionnumber>
<Patient>
   <PatientCharacteristics>
      <dateOfBirth>1900-01-01</dateOfBirth>
      <patientCode>1</patientCode>
      <DebutOfSymptoms>1935-01-01</DebutOfSymptoms>
      <sex>1</sex>
      <identifier>7705</identifier>
   </PatientCharacteristics>
</Patient>
<Patient>
   <PatientCharacteristics>
      <dateOfBirth>1919-01-01</dateOfBirth>
      <patientCode>3</patientCode>
      <DebutOfSymptoms>1925-01-01</DebutOfSymptoms>
      <sex>2</sex>
      <identifier>7405</identifier>
   </PatientCharacteristics>
</Patient>
</Patientdata>
```

**Edit2:** I have pared it right back to it's bare components

XSLT:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <PatientData>
            <xsl:value-of select="x:Patientdata"/>
            <Versionnumber>
                <xsl:value-of select="x:Patientdata/x:Versionnumber"/>
            </Versionnumber>
            <Patient>
                <xsl:value-of select="x:Patientdata/x:Patient"/>
                <PatientCharacterstics>
                    <xsl:value-of select="x:Patientdata/Patient/PatientCharacteristics"/>
                    <patientCode>
                        <xsl:value-of select="x:Patientdata/Patient/PatientCharacteristics/patientCode"/>
                    </patientCode>
                    <identifier>
                        <xsl:value-of select="x:Patientdata/Patient/PatientCharacteristics/identifier"/>
                    </identifier>
                    <sex>
                        <xsl:value-of select="x:Patientdata/x:Patient/x:PatientCharacteristics/x:sex"/>
                    </sex>
                    <dateOfBirth>
                        <xsl:value-of select="x:Patientdata/Patient/PatientCharacteristics/dateOfBirth"/>
                    </dateOfBirth>
                    <DebutOfSymptoms>
                        <xsl:value-of select="x:Patientdata/Patient/PatientCharacteristics/DebutOfSymptoms"/>
                    </DebutOfSymptoms>

                </PatientCharacterstics>
            </Patient>
        </PatientData>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Patientdata>
<Versionnumber>1</Versionnumber>
<Patient>
   <PatientCharacteristics>
      <dateOfBirth>1900-01-01</dateOfBirth>
      <patientCode>1</patientCode>
      <DebutOfSymptoms>1935-01-01</DebutOfSymptoms>
      <sex>1</sex>
      <identifier>7705</identifier>
   </PatientCharacteristics>
</Patient>
<Patient>
   <PatientCharacteristics>
      <dateOfBirth>1919-01-01</dateOfBirth>
      <patientCode>3</patientCode>
      <DebutOfSymptoms>1925-01-01</DebutOfSymptoms>
      <sex>2</sex>
      <identifier>7405</identifier>
   </PatientCharacteristics>
</Patient>
</Patientdata>
```

And this is the output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<PatientData xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"><Versionnumber/>
<Patient>
<PatientCharacterstics>
<patientCode/>
<identifier/>
<sex/>
<dateOfBirth/>
<DebutOfSymptoms/>
</PatientCharacterstics>
</Patient>
</PatientData>
```

When the output SHOULD be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Patientdata>
<Versionnumber>1</Versionnumber>
<Patient>
   <PatientCharacteristics>
      <patientCode>1</patientCode>
      <identifier>7705</identifier>
      <sex>1</sex>
      <dateOfBirth>1900-01-01</dateOfBirth>
      <DebutOfSymptoms>1935-01-01</DebutOfSymptoms>
   </PatientCharacteristics>
</Patient>
<Patient>
   <PatientCharacteristics>
      <patientCode>3</patientCode>
      <identifier>7405</identifier>
      <dateOfBirth>1919-01-01</dateOfBirth>     
      <sex>2</sex>
      <DebutOfSymptoms>1925-01-01</DebutOfSymptoms>
   </PatientCharacteristics>
</Patient>
</Patientdata>
```

Comment: You have to show us some sample input XML for anybody to help you.

Comment: Please show enough of the XML that we can see the root and the namespace declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your source XML data has a default namespace declaration like

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
```

then your problem is that your template is trying to match an `x` element with no namespace. You need the opening tag to be

```
<xsl:template match="/x:x">
```

However, if what you think your template is doing is applying a default namespace, and the root element of your XML data is `Patientdata` and not `x`, then you are misunderstanding. Your template should match just the root element like this

```
<xsl:template match="/">
```

Note also that you need the namespace prefix on *every step* in an XPath expression, like this

```
<xsl:value-of select="x:Patientdata/x:Patient/x:PatientCharacteristics/x:sex"/>
```

---

**Update**

Now that you have shown more of your data I can understand better what it is you want. Your statement that you had declared a default namespace, your `xmlns:x` namespace declaration, and the template that matches `/x` were all red herrings, and it seems that you don't need any special namespaces at all.

I wonder if perhaps you weren't looking far enough down the output that your transform produced, because you have several elements like `<xsl:value-of select="x:Patientdata"/>` in your transform, which are superfluous and cause all of the text descendants of the input element to be copied to the output. The rest of the information is there too but it is several lines down the page.

If I remove the `x` namespace prefx declaration and its uses, as well as those unnecessary `value-of` elements, your transform works fine. I have also added an `output` element to enable indentation of the output so that it looks nice.

This

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <PatientData>
      <Versionnumber>
        <xsl:value-of select="Patientdata/Versionnumber"/>
      </Versionnumber>
      <Patient>
        <PatientCharacterstics>
          <patientCode>
            <xsl:value-of select="Patientdata/Patient/PatientCharacteristics/patientCode"/>
          </patientCode>
          <identifier>
            <xsl:value-of select="Patientdata/Patient/PatientCharacteristics/identifier"/>
          </identifier>
          <sex>
            <xsl:value-of select="Patientdata/Patient/PatientCharacteristics/sex"/>
          </sex>
          <dateOfBirth>
            <xsl:value-of select="Patientdata/Patient/PatientCharacteristics/dateOfBirth"/>
          </dateOfBirth>
          <DebutOfSymptoms>
            <xsl:value-of select="Patientdata/Patient/PatientCharacteristics/DebutOfSymptoms"/>
          </DebutOfSymptoms>

        </PatientCharacterstics>
      </Patient>
    </PatientData>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <PatientData>
      <Versionnumber>
        <xsl:value-of select="Patientdata/Versionnumber"/>
      </Versionnumber>
      <Patient>
        <PatientCharacterstics>
          <patientCode>
            <xsl:value-of select="Patientdata/Patient/PatientCharacteristics/patientCode"/>
          </patientCode>
          <identifier>
            <xsl:value-of select="Patientdata/Patient/PatientCharacteristics/identifier"/>
          </identifier>
          <sex>
            <xsl:value-of select="Patientdata/Patient/PatientCharacteristics/sex"/>
          </sex>
          <dateOfBirth>
            <xsl:value-of select="Patientdata/Patient/PatientCharacteristics/dateOfBirth"/>
          </dateOfBirth>
          <DebutOfSymptoms>
            <xsl:value-of select="Patientdata/Patient/PatientCharacteristics/DebutOfSymptoms"/>
          </DebutOfSymptoms>

        </PatientCharacterstics>
      </Patient>
    </PatientData>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces this output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PatientData>
   <Versionnumber>1</Versionnumber>
   <Patient>
      <PatientCharacterstics>
         <patientCode>1</patientCode>
         <identifier>7705</identifier>
         <sex>1</sex>
         <dateOfBirth>1900-01-01</dateOfBirth>
         <DebutOfSymptoms>1935-01-01</DebutOfSymptoms>
      </PatientCharacterstics>
   </Patient>
</PatientData>
```

---

**Update 2**

XSLT is really a *declarative* language, and while it has many procedural elements like `for-each` and `if`, it is better to use templates to define how a source doument is to be processed.

I realise you have cut down the transform, and all I can see that you are trying to do is to reorder the elements within each `PatientCharacterstics` element. This template will do that for you.

The first template is a generic copy template, that matches all nodes and processes them by copying the opening tag, processing any children, and copying the closing tag. The second template is a sepcial one that matches the element to be changed - `PatientCharacteristics` - which is processed by copying the tags in the same way, but processing the children in the specific order required.

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PatientCharacteristics">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="patientCode"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="identifier"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="sex"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="dateOfBirth"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="DebutOfSymptoms"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Patientdata>
   <Versionnumber>1</Versionnumber>
   <Patient>
      <PatientCharacteristics>
         <patientCode>1</patientCode>
         <identifier>7705</identifier>
         <sex>1</sex>
         <dateOfBirth>1900-01-01</dateOfBirth>
         <DebutOfSymptoms>1935-01-01</DebutOfSymptoms>
      </PatientCharacteristics>
   </Patient>
   <Patient>
      <PatientCharacteristics>
         <patientCode>3</patientCode>
         <identifier>7405</identifier>
         <sex>2</sex>
         <dateOfBirth>1919-01-01</dateOfBirth>
         <DebutOfSymptoms>1925-01-01</DebutOfSymptoms>
      </PatientCharacteristics>
   </Patient>
</Patientdata>
```

Comment: Hi Borodin, I'm sorry I don't understand, I tried the above but it didn't work. I have added in a second edit to condense what the essence of what I am trying to achieve. Hope that's clearer!

Comment: Now that I have seen more of your data I have updated my answer to offer a proper solution.

Comment: THANKS! Just one thing, how do I make it output the second patient?

Comment: @Sarah-Ann: I have written a transform that does what I think you intend.